# The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404

Tags: iis

I have hosted a website on the server but found that none of the images are loading on the site.

The images are present in the `images` folder, and `images` has correct permissions.

When I browse `domain/images`, I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: `/Images/`
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1

But if I copy the folder `images` to `images1`, then requesting `domain/images1` works as I expect.

Comment: Is the Images folder part of the project? When you put an index.htm file in the images folder does it display? 404 is the server not finding it, 403 is what I would expect if the permissions were not set right.

Comment: Hello Jun,  thx for responding.  I have checked and made sure that there is nothing wrong with the permission, have deployed the site on test server with same data but still get the same error, seems something in coding is blocking the images folder from loading.

Comment: can you request the image to check if it displays?
http://www.url.com/Images/someimage.jpg?

Comment: Hello Jua,   Thanks for responding back, as imagine the issue was with coding, images folder was blocked in back-end i.e coding  :)